# CSS3 Divs side by side, arrangement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with divs arrangement.
Here is my code:

```css
#container{
    
}
#block1{
    vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#block2{
    vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block1"></div>
</div>
```

And issue is arrangement, it looks like this:
[image: wrong]
But i need to look like this. Arrange divs up without white spaces.
[image: good]
Any ideas here? Thanks :).
Here is JSFiddle, so you can play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/cn2r3tga/

Comment: Offtopic: an `id` should be unique. Use `class` instead, if you want to reuse it.

Comment: Looks like another question that needs [**Masonry.js**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css

```
 #container{

}
#block1{
  background-color: #FF0000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
#block2{
   background-color: #0000FF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
.alignment{
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="alignment">
        <div id="block1"></div>
        <div id="block1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment">
        <div id="block2"></div>
        <div id="block1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: ID of any HTML control should be unique

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your div's like this (also changed the `id` to `class`):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block1"></div>
</div>
```

Then use float instead of inline-block:

```
.block1{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.block2{
    float: right;
    width:49%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cn2r3tga/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can group them into two divs and then get the desired result. As shown below:

```css
#container{
    
}
.left{
    float:left;
    width:49%;
    margin-right:2%
}
.right{
    float:right;
    width:49%;
}
.block1{
    vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color:red;
}
.block2{
    vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="block2"></div>
        <div class="block1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/cn2r3tga/3/

Updated fiddle.

```
"float:right"
```

should be used for those going to the right.

Answer (score 1):

first you use id which should be used only once so use classes instead which you can re-use as many times as you want.

Secondly I would add another 2 div within your .container to make the result you want and add the css to keep the shape your want:

```
<div class="container">
<div calss="left">
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block1"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
<div class="block2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```